# Need relevant .xml file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I need relevant.xml file for `<checkout_onepage_index>` in Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Comment: go to   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/ and see for checkout_index_index.xml  & checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers

Comment: I want  to override this in magento 2 <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment"></reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, the action handle **checkout_onepage_index** has been changed to **checkout_index_index**.

Also, Magento 2 has split the layout files based on layout handle. So, you can find equivalent layout file named as **`checkout_index_index.xml`**.

This file can be in many different modules since any module can change/modify the layout of any other module's action in Magento 2.

Comment: But, i want to add my custom block in **<reference name="checkout.onepage.payment">**  inside chcekout_index_index.xml  in magento 2 don't have chcekout.onepage.payment name in checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: Please answer me?